# How to reset Twitter Bootstrap Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reset, bar-chart

i need to reset a bootstrap bar chart before i set their values.
So i need to reset chart completely, but i don't know how to reset values and animations without need to set them to "0".
Any idea?

My .js looks like this:

```
function chart(){

$.get("/apicountryajax",function(data) {

    if($('.verticalChart')) {

        //NEED RESET HERE

        var i=0;

        $('.singleBar').each(function(){

            var dataObj=data['objects'][i];
            var cName=dataObj['countryName'];
            var cCount=parseFloat(dataObj['countryCount'])*100;
            var percent=cCount+"%";
            i++;

            $(this).find('.value').animate({height:percent}, 2000,                    function() {

                $(this).find('span').fadeIn();
                $(this).find('span').html(percent);

            });
            $(this).find('.title').html(cName); 
        }); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Where did you get this code? Is it a custom built Boostrap thing?

Comment: This code is a "override" of a bootstrap bar chart...